# How to know which csv delimiter is being used on a pc using php?

Tags: excel

I am generating a csv file.
I would like to set up the delimiter dynamically, that is, get the value of the list-separator set up on the pc and then use it in my csv.

Is it possible??

Comment: "On a PC?" AFAIK there's no "PC specific delimiter", it's up to each program/user/file what delimiter to use.

Comment: Actually I encountered a problem. I did generate a CSV using ',' as delimiter..But on my client side, it was not working. I replaced the delimiter by ';' and it works on the client side. So I would like to know how to set that so as it work on my side and client side also?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not. You want your csv to open in Excel. Correct? Then use [TAB] and direct the file to be saved ".xls" and not ".csv". The worst case is a warning message at opening regarding the file format for the user, but data will be visible in cells for sure.

Another approach for excel files is to use Excel(X)ML; it's very simple for raw data (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-xml-in-excel-HA010206396.aspx)

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the warning message from displaying??

Comment: Only if you have users using very old versions of Excel. But as far as I know it's an acceptable message by the users who know what to expect. If you want to avoid it use ExcelML.

Answer (score 0):

> I did generate a CSV using ',' as delimiter..But on my client side, it was not working. I replaced the delimiter by ';' and it works on the client side.

That means the client expected `;` instead of `,`. You cannot know what the client expects unless he tells you. There are an uncountable number of programs that use the CSV format, there's no universal way to figure out which delimiter they expect. Usually it works the other way around: you create the CSV and specify to the client what delimiter you have used. There's no technical protocol to do this though, CSV is too informal to have any such universal specification.